Не получается определить верное значение строки в массиве
Дана следующая задача: Зафиксируйте состояние генератора случайных чисел с помощью NumPy-функции random.seed(). Аргумент функции совпадает с номером варианта. Сгенерируйте одномерный массив из 1000 значений (закон распределения и его параметры: нормальное с параметрами 0, 1), поместите его в переменную x. Преобразуйте массив x в массив заданной размерности: 500×2. Определите значение на указанной позиции: строка двести девяносто семь, столбец один. Значение при выводе округлите до 2 знаков с помощью NumPy-функции round(). Для вывода используйте функцию print().
Написал код:
import numpy as np

x = np.random.seed(21)

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000).reshape(500, 2)

y = x[297, 0]

z = np.round(y, 2)

print(z)

При проверке в IDLE проблем не возникает, округляет нормально. Но при отправке задания возникает ошибка, он указывает, что число ответа не совпадает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая здесь ошибка.
Такой код тоже не принимается:
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(21)

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000).reshape(500, 2)
y = x[297, 1]
z = np.round(y, 2)
print(z)


Перечитайте, какая позиция задана

я менял уже столбец и на 1 и на 2, номер строки тоже в обе стороны крутил: не помогает

Два момента:
y = x[297, 0]

а должно быть [297, 1] добавлено: или [296, 0]
Но главное - вы дважды генерируете набор данных, таким образом, он отличается от того, что ожидался при заданном seed (перед второй генерацией seed уже другой)
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(21)

w = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)

x = w.reshape(500, 2)

y = x[297, 1]

z = np.round(y, 2)

print(z)


спасибо, думал про это. Но каким образом избежать двойной генерации?

Убрать первую )

удаление строки там тоже ничего не решило

новый код вставил в описание

Остаётся еще вероятность, что они хотят [296, 0]

Благодарю! Именно 296, 0 сработало
